# How do I set the opacity of a vertex in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency, opacity

The following snippet draws a gray square.

```
glColor3b(50, 50, 50);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-1.0, +1.0, 0.0); // top left
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0); // bottom left
glVertex3f(+1.0, -1.0, 0.0); // bottom right
glVertex3f(+1.0, +1.0, 0.0); // top right
glEnd();
```

In my application, behind this single square exists a colored cube.

What function should I use to make square (and only this square) opaque?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617370/opengl-alpha-transparency

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the init function, use these two lines:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

And in your render function, ensure that `glColor4f` is used instead of `glColor3f`, and set the 4th argument to the level of opacity required.

```
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-1.0, +1.0, 0.0); // top left
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0); // bottom left
glVertex3f(+1.0, -1.0, 0.0); // bottom right
glVertex3f(+1.0, +1.0, 0.0); // top right
glEnd();
```

Comment: Saving lives even 11 year later.

Answer (score 2):

glColor4f(float r,float g, float b, flaot alpha);
(in your case maybe clColor4b)
also make sure, that blending is enabled.
(you have to reset the color to non-alpha afterwads, which might involve a glGet* to save the old vertexcolor)

Answer (score 2):

You can set colors per vertex

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5); // red, 50% alpha
glVertex3f(-1.0, +1.0, 0.0); // top left
// Make sure to set the color back since the color state persists
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0); // bottom left
glVertex3f(+1.0, -1.0, 0.0); // bottom right
glVertex3f(+1.0, +1.0, 0.0); // top right
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glColor4` instead of `glColor3`.  For example:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE);
glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.5f);
```

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, doesn't seem to be working for me, what could I be doing wrong?