# How to use alpha transparency in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency, alpha

Here's my code:

```
void display(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,50);
    glutCreateWindow("glut test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(8);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor4f(.23,.78,.32,1.0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glColor4f(.23,.78,.32,0.1);
    glVertex2f(0.1,0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

The problem is that these two points appear identical (even when I set the alpha to 0). Is there something I missed to enable alpha transparency?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just a guess, but could it be that you dont have a background color ? So, when your rendering the second vertex which has alpha 0.1, there is no background to compute the proper color ? Just a guess, been years since i used opengl.

Comment: Yep, this was it. I should've added: 
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable( GL_BLEND ); 
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);` 
but only after glutCreateWindow()

Answer (score 77):

have you glEnable'd alpha blending?  And have you set up your blend parameters?  You can't just set the alpha you need to setup various other parameters in OpenGL.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
```

Comment: OpenGL requires most everything to be enabled. A good place to start looking. (Disabling and enabling different operations at different times can lead to the most interesting effects.)

Comment: The initialization order also matters. Seems the window has to be initialized before glEnable() and glBlendFunc() is  set.

Comment: @user3078414 The context needs to be created, but not (strictly speaking) attached to a window. OpenGL only cares about contexts, an off-screen one will do fine as far as it is concerned.