# Does SFML support transparency?

Tags: opengl, transparency, alpha, sfml

Hi I am trying to draw a translucent sphere using OpenGL / glut;

Easiest thing I think is to post the code: This is what I have at the moment;

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);

sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 32;
settings.stencilBits = 0;
settings.antialiasingLevel = 0;

sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "insert title", sf::Style::Default, settings);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);


glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);


bool running = true;
while(running)
{
    sf::Event e;
    while(window.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if(e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            running = false;
        }

        if(e.type == sf::Event::Resized)
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, e.size.width, e.size.height);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

            glLoadIdentity();
            gluPerspective(45.0, (double)e.size.width / (double)e.size.height, 0.1, 2000.0);

            gluLookAt(0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,1,0);

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        }
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor4d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

    glutWireSphere(0.5, 4, 4);

    window.display();
}
```

Ran this thing under optirun and without optirun... No transparency though!

I read somewhere the context must have an alpha buffer... Does SFML support this?

Comment: This code has all of the hallmarks of copy-and-paste coding. Please don't do that.

Comment: There's no copying and pasting here.

Comment: Are you using GLUT xor SFML?

Comment: GLUT to draw a sphere, SFML to render.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721705/how-do-i-set-the-opacity-of-a-vertex-in-opengl

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very confused.

FreeGLUT and SFML *do the same thing* with regard to OpenGL: they create windows with OpenGL contexts. You *should not* be using them both in the same application.

Also, you can't call OpenGL functions until you've created the window. And those functions will *only* affect the current context. Those functions will have *no effect* on the new context you create with SFML. Your code simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EdwardBird: You're still calling GLUT functions (and therefore including it in your SFML project). Do not mix GLUT and SFML.

Comment: How else am I going to draw a sphere?

Comment: GLU have functions for drawing simple forms like spheres as well : http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluSphere.xml

Comment: @EdwardBird: By drawing a series of triangles that approximate the shape of a sphere. GLUT isn't doing anything you can't do on your own.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hahahahaha, "draw a series of triangles" why make life difficult?!

Provide some source which draws a sphere and I will be impressed.

Comment: If it works and you don't care about basic quality or performance then I guess it is fine, but I have NO idea what unholy things mixing together these libs can will actually do to your application :) With SFML you are supposed to define your own mesh data. If you dont want to generate it there are plenty of resources out there for making simple mesh loaders. Then you can simply make your geometry in for example Blender.